# What is the best practice : to publish data to azure iothub or directly to azure tablestorage

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-table-storage, azure-iot-hub

I have an web app.  The current structure\flow is as below.

- This has a webservice which is used by the Device module to place the device-specific-data into my Table STorage.
- At the UI end SignalR is employed to display on Dashboard(view-cshtml) the latest value posted to the cloud as and when the data from the device gets into the TableStorage.
- Data from different devices are expected to get into TableStorage and at the UI end, as per the device selected, the related data are diplayed.

**My Query**

1. Instead of directly publishing to  TableStorage, Will there be any benefit to have the Azure resource, IOTHub, to which the devices can be publishing its data?  If so please let me know on it.

   -->  a. In this case where should the data that's placed on IoTHub be taken to, for storing all received data for future reference?

   --->  b. I have earlier used an option of using StreamAnalytics , used a query to insert data receiving at IoTHub end to TableStorage. 
   Is is the only\good option available?

   ---> c. Or do we have any other options to hold the data published to IoTHub?
2. Is the current flow of inserting the data directly to TableStorage from the device OK(best practice?)? If not please suggest the best way of approaching the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been reading on taking data with IoTHub and TableStorage.
My analysis and most importantly my experience using Table Storage, has given me some understanding on this.

There's a good reason to publish data to IoTHub before taking it to store in storageTable.

One of the benefits I see in my case, its best to publish data to IoTHub, is that I can pick up the data received on IoTHub to display it (which is the latest received)on a Dashboard(UI) ; instead of querying the storagetable to get the latest.

**Reason**

Though publishing data to TableStorage too works fine, it may encounter some performance issue.

- The issue here is when the data grows in TableStorage we may get a
  hard blow on the performance side.i.e if the TableStorage PK is designed such as that, it may build up to attain huge data under a partition at some point of time. This leads to a case of querying a huge data.
- Also TableStorage's limitation on having only index on PartitionKey and RowKey; So it  works best - performance wise - when accessed via PartitionKey and RowKey.

  - Even if we access(query) via PartitionKey and RowKey there still will have huge data if the the Storage Table's data structure is designed to have such a PartitionKey.
    For instance if we collect 10 Device Signal details in TableStorage and design each PK to have the corresponding SignalID (such that each signal is grouped within a partition) ==> then the data coming in for Signal at one point will be huge within the partition. This in turn impacts the performance very badly.

Answer (score 0):

The messages of device-to-cloud are routed to the built-in service-facing endpoint (messages/events) that is compatible with [Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/).This messages are retained by IoT Hub. The default is one day, but it can be increased to seven days.You can modify the retention time, either programmatically through the [IoT Hub resource provider REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource), or by using the Azure portal.So you need not to publish the data to Table Storage directly, IoT Hub can store the data as cache.

[Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction) consists of three data services: Blob storage, File storage, and Queue storage. Blob storage supports both standard and premium storage, with premium storage using only SSDs for the fastest performance possible. Another feature is cool storage, allowing you to store large amounts of rarely accessed data for a lower cost.

Comment: 1. The requirement is to hold the data permanently like we we do in the classical Database. The web app should have options to view the historical data. So does the IoTHub support this? ____ 2.What is the benefit of publishing to IoTHub instead of directly inserting to TableStorage?

Comment: 1.IoTHub does not support holding the data permanently. 2.You can get the information and benefits about IoTHub from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/).

Comment: Ok Thanks MichaelXu.